# Where was the French movie "À gauche en sortant de l'ascenseur" filmed?

Tags: film-location

The film title is [Door on the Left as You Leave the Elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_on_the_Left_as_You_Leave_the_Elevator) or [À gauche en sortant de l'ascenseur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80_gauche_en_sortant_de_l%27ascenseur).
Most of the action takes place inside several rooms, which are probably shot in a studio, but there are also some exterior shots of a building present.

[image]

Where is this building located?

The address `Paris, rue Lauzier` is fictional, but the building is not.

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, identification questions are considered off-topic by this community, which includes identifying locations.

Comment: @Charles It is not. We have the appropriately used tag 'film-location' exclusively for this usage, mentioning it is "*for questions trying to determine where a film was shot*", and it currently has 121 questions. And apparently a few users voted according to this misconception.

Answer (score 3):

According to L2TC.com - Lieux de Tournage Cinématographique [1](https://www.l2tc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=461) and [2](https://www.l2tc.com/cherche.php?titre=A+gauche+en+sortant+de+l%27ascenseur&exact=oui&annee=1988) (L2LC roughly translated means "Places Where Movies Were Shot") there are several places:

1. [Deauville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deauville) - Promenade Michel d'Ornano - Promenade des Planches - Bar de la mer
2. [Levallois-Perret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levallois-Perret) - rue d'Alsace and rue de Courcelles
3. [Paris 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3rd_arrondissement_of_Paris) - Galerie Daniel Templon, 30 rue de Beaubourg
4. [Paris 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4th_arrondissement_of_Paris) - 35 rue Quincampoix
5. [Paris 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5th_arrondissement_of_Paris) - Rue Saint-Séverin

All indoor scenes were shot in the studio.

References are to be translated, please leave a comment if necessary and I'll do it. Same if places need more details, such are restaurant or mall and others, as the only available source is not in English, it needs more time and work. With the names, it should be possible to use Google maps to sneak around maybe and match screenshots of the movie.